# Mysql query with join should return nested array

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have some issue with output of my sql query.
I have two table say Table1 and Table2.
each row in table1 may have multiple rows in table2.
So, on retrieving using below query.I want the output array must have the table2 data in the same index.

here is my query.

> select * from table1 left join table2 on table1.id = table2.table1_id

What im getting is

```
(int) 0 => array(
                'table1' => array('id' => '1'),
                'table2' => array('id' => '12','table1_id' => '1')
                ),
(int) 1 => array(
                'table1' => array('id' => '1'),
                'table2' => array('id' => '13','table1_id' => '1')
                ),          
(int) 2 => array(
                'table1' => array('id' => '2'),
                'table2' => array('id' => '14','table1_id' => '2')
                ),              
(int) 3 => array(
                'table1' => array('id' => '2'),
                'table2' => array('id' => '15','table1_id' => '2')
                ),              
(int) 4 => array(
                'table1' => array('id' => '2'),
                'table2' => array('id' => '16','table1_id' => '2')
                )
```

I want the output to be in below format.

```
(int) 0 => array(
                'table1' => array(id =>1),  
                'table2' => array('id' => '12','table1_id' => '1'),
                'table2' => array('id' => '13','table1_id' => '1')
                ), 
(int) 1 => array(
                'table1' => array(id =>2),
                'table2' => array('id' => '14','table1_id' => '2'),
                'table2' => array('id' => '15','table1_id' => '2'),
                'table2' => array('id' => '16','table1_id' => '2')
                )
```

Im not sure if this possible with sql query.
Anyone can hep me. Thanks